# AWS Docker Practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

The problem I am having is that the python application within my Docker image needs arguments for the read-folder path and the write-out path. How do I go about setting the Docker image to know the folder path and the write-out path are S3 buckets?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. You can your docker containers with environment variables supplied in the run command.

   docker run --name my_image -e SOME_ENV=hi some_image
2. You can use AWS SSM to store the two file paths, and pull the paths via boto3 ssm client. This is obviously done in the application side.
3. You can build your image with the file paths set in your dockerfile. It's similar to step 1, but it's embedded into your docker image, rather than being supplied in run time.

What's wrong with hard coding the file paths?

Comment: I am afraid that the application by itself will not be able to handle the files. My vision was to set up some service where it will read each file in the bucket and run the application for each (write results to other bucket) while the queue message would tell it which files were already processed. I would be able to scale this and parallelize effectively. Though I suppose I could do it all in the app.

Comment: You can just supply the file names as arguments to your python file via

docker run your_python_image -c "python3 main.py $SOMEFILE $ANOTHERFILE"

Comment: Ok. I will do that then.